# Why can't I have 'int' as the type of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, integer

I want to declare an `ArrayList` of type `int`.

Why does the following give me an error:

```
ArrayList<int> list1 = new ArrayList<int>();
```

But the following works:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

?

Comment: Because `int` isn't an object in the same context the `Integer` is

Comment: You can use `TIntArrayList` if you want something which wraps `int[]`

Comment: `int` is primitive datatype we can use wrapper class in `ArrayList`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`ArrayList` can only reference types, not primitives. `Integer` is a class, not a primitive.

When you declare `ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>()`, you're creating an `ArrayList` which will store the `Integer` type, not the `int` primitive.

If you want to read about the difference between primitive and reference types, check out http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/primitiveVsRef.html

Comment: You probably don't need the <Integer> type argument on the right of the new expression.
`ArrayList<Integer> list1=new ArrayList();` works too.

Answer (score 14):

Because `int` is a *primitive type*.  Only *reference types* can be used as generic parameters.

Comment: Even before generics (before Java 5) this restriction was there so I doesn't think its the only reason

Comment: @Pangea: Sure, you can't do `new ArrayList().add(5)`.  But the OP is asking about the error wrt that particular line of code...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth You can do that actually. It just will be adding an `Integer` not an `int` value.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Ah, you're right.  I guess this didn't work prior to autoboxing?

Answer (score 12):

The short answer is that generics (like `ArrayList<Integer>`) do not accept primitive types (`int`), only objects (`Integer`).

This is because classes like `ArrayList` are implemented as using Objects. Since every class inherits from Object, the compiler can just plug in other classes. But primitive types (like `int`) do not inherit from Object, for they are not classes. So, Sun/Oracle made the `Integer` class to help with this.

So, in short: `int` is not an `Object`.

Comment: This is the best answer because it explains this declaration, which works fine: `ArrayList<int[]>`

Answer (score 1):

All the answers above answer why but the root of this question is frequent auto boxing and unboxing of the primitive data types. This problem is already solved by IntBuffer or ChadBuffer or you name the primitive type it's already there in the nio folder. Next time if you want to use primitive ArrayList don't use List instead use IntBuffer

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a `primitive`. It is not a `Object`.

Refer this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/) for further details.

Comment: Link only answers are not encouraged at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

int is a primitive data type but Integer is a class so an arrayList array can only take reference types as its parameter not primitive type

Answer (score 0):

int is not an Object and hence if list type is int, implementations of the list cannot be done.