# How do pointers work with primitive types in Java?

Tags: java, pointers, primitive-types

I was reading [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), and in the accepted answer, I read something that I did not quite understand:

> ```
> int x;
> x = 10;
> ```
>
> In this example the variable x is an int and Java will initialize it
>   to 0 for you. When you assign it to 10 in the second line your value
>   10 is written into the memory location pointed to by x.

I thought for primitive types, the variable was the memory address of the actual value; where as for complex types, the variable was merely the memory address of a pointer to the actual value.  But the quoted answer above tells me I am wrong.  It says "the memory location pointed to by x."

So if x is pointing to a memory address which stores the actual value, how is a primitive type different from a complex type?  I did not know primitive types even had pointers.  How do pointers work with primitive types?

Comment: is not it **a reference** into the memory location?

Comment: @KickButtowski For complex types, yes.  What I don't get is that something is pointed to by x, which is a primitive type.

Comment: when you say point to, it reminds me pointer in c and c++ which we do not have such a thing in Java.

Comment: @KickButtowski I did not know that.  I thought pointers behaved the same in all languages.  So what does "pointed to" mean in Java when referring to primitive types?  (My limited understanding is that pointing to something means a memory address's value is the memory address of another value as seen in complex types.)

Comment: I think you should take a look at difference between reference and pointer . google it

Comment: @KickButtowski Thanks!  I will try and wade my way thru all the C++ reference and pointer material and look for something Java specific.

Comment: "In this example the variable x is an int and Java will initialize it to 0 for you" - this is not true

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A primitive type and complex type are different from each other primarily in the way data is stored. You're actually looking at the differences between a primitive type and a *class type*

> **1.** Every variable is stored as a location in the computer memory.
>
> The above statement applies to both primitive types and also class
>   types.
>
> The differences:
>
> **2.** For a **primitive type:  the value of the variable is stored in the memory location assigned to the variable**.
>
> That means if we assigned `int x = 10`, the value of `x` is stored in
>   where the value of `10` is stored, i.e the memory location. That means
>   when we "look" at x, '10' is stored there. Maybe it would help to
>   think of it more like an "assignment" where you command that x be
>   equal to 10.
>
> **3.** For a class type: It only stores the memory address of **the object** that **stores** the value. It does not directly hold the
>   object itself.
>
> Integer x = 10 will have a memory address that points to object of
>   type int, which will then hold the value of 10. This is known as a
>   **reference**. Think of it as directory that tells you to go to which shelf to actually retrieve the value.

**Also**

Class types are also known as reference types, or object types, that is they all mean an Object of a class (be it an Integer class, or MyPerson class).

Primitive types are not reference types because **they do not hold references** (memory addresses).

This distinction is the reason for "wrapper classes" in daily use, and types such as `Integer` are seen as a wrapper class to an `int`, to allow for data manipulation such as storing integers in a data structure such as an ArrayList. Because `ints` a primitive data type, is not an `object`, while `Integer` is. Since **primitive types are not objects**, we have to put them into a class in order for us to add them to Lists, Dictionaries etc. This way we have a List of Objects (which, point to the primitive types) but they are not a naked primitive datatype by itself. See [this SO question for further info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349011/why-i-cant-have-int-in-the-type-of-arraylist)

Additional reading on the difference between a primitive and non-primitive (aka Class/reference/object type) is detailed [here](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/difference-between-a-primitive-type-and-a-class-type/). They have a nice diagram illustrating it too.

Comment: I changed your format a little , so It can be easy to read. hope it is ok with you. I have already plus one u too

Comment: So is it just that I got confused with the wording of "the memory location pointed to by x."?  They did not mean to imply that the memory location of x pointed anywhere...they just meant x?

Comment: @KickButtowski just saw that. definitely okay with me. thank you! I added some info so I mirrored your edits. Please edit accordingly!

Comment: @Evorlor precisely. If you think of it in terms of programming languages that use pointers (C based ones for example), the difference is that a primitive type is just int x, while a class type will be a class that has a pointer (mem address) to int x. If that makes sense... the link I gave has a more thorough write up, and explains it in more detail than I attempted to, i think.