# Adding a new object to an ArrayList with only one data type

Tags: java, object, arraylist

So I understand that you have to make a "new" object when adding an object to an arraylist:

```
ex:
    ArrayList<CookieOrder> orders = new ArrayList<CookieOrder>();

    orders.add(new CookieOrder("cookie", 5));
```

but do you have to do this when the arraylist consists of only one data type

```
ex:
    ArrayList<int> numbers = new ArrayList<int>();

    numbers.add(new int(2));
    or
    numbers.add(2);
```

Comment: You can't use keyword new with primitives, you just declare them and assign a value, you use new with objects. And you cant have an ArrayList of type int.

Comment: You do use the keyword 'new' with arrays of primitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to initialize a new "integer" object, because the integer already exists. 
You can add to an integer arraylist by doing just array.add(2);

Also, ArrayLists in java do not allow primitive types such as ints and doubles as storage.
You have to use the classes of them,
For example

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

For more information, see this post. 
[Why I can't have int in the type of ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349011/why-i-cant-have-int-in-the-type-of-arraylist)