# Java autoboxing and unboxing issue

Tags: java

Java compiler takes care of casting primitive data types and their wrapper classes..But my doubt is that although java compiler performs type casting all by itself, why is it that it prints an error when I try to convert an Array to ArrayList with int array as parameter..Like:

```
int[] val = {1,2,3,4,5};
ArrayList<Integer> newval = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(val));
```

> Error: no suitable constructor found for `ArrayList(List<int[]>)`

Why is the compiler not casting int to Integer?

Comment: There's no auto-boxing of primitive arrays to arrays of the corresponding wrapper type.

Comment: Using a `Stream` to convert `int` into a `Integer` then collect the all would be the simplest I guess...

Comment: Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is called unboxing but not collections to their respective in arrays format.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `IntStream` to help you with the "boxing" of primitives

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4};
List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(a)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will iterate the array, boxed the `int` into an `Integer` and then you just have to collect the `Stream` into a `List` with the `Collectors`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a `ArrayList<primitive types>` Source: [why you can't create a Arraylist of primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349011/why-i-cant-have-int-in-the-type-of-arraylist). Instead, use an adaptor class:

```
class Adapter{

private int[] value;

adapter(int[] value){

this.value = value;
 }
 public int[] getValue(){
 return value;
   }
  }
```

And then add it to the `ArrayList<Adapter> AL = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Then just use an `Integer` directly... Also, a class should start with a uppercase ;)

Comment: @AxelH changed adapter -> Adapter. Thanks! I just suggested other way to work with primitive types in collections.

Comment: How would you use that `Adapter` for a `List<Integer>` ? Not sure what is the plan here...

Answer (score 0):

There is no autoboxing here; perhaps you meant to do:

```
Integer[] val = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Comment: I guess the array initialization is just for the MCVE ;) but it could be that simple ...

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] val = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

For Primitive arrays:

```
List<int[]> vv = Arrays.asList(val);
```

Will get List of arrays because autoboxing wont work when we try to convert the primitive array into list

For Object array type:

```
Integer[] val = {1,2,3,4,5};
List<Integer> vv = Arrays.asList(val);
```

Compiler will use autoboxing

Answer (score -2):

`Arrays.asList` accepts an array of objects - not primitives (in many cases the compiler is smart enough to interchange through something called autoboxing - in this case not). Using a simple loop you can add the items of the array to the `List`.

Comment: While the solution of yours is wrong, I don't see why people are downvoting. The explanation is correct

Comment: @Midnightas well a solution that is not a solution doesn't belong ... The explanation is at most a comment.

Comment: @Midnightas Same as AxelH here.

Comment: @AxelH The question asks "why", not "how to fix this". Thus the answer is valid.